# Snowflake Ownership inheritance - Is it possible to stop ownership privilege from being inherited?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to check whether the ownership of a schema can be restricted from being inherited by another role. I have a managed schema, which is owned (has ownership privilege granted to it) by a role A. Role B inherits Role A, but I do not want Role B to inherit the ownership privilege.

Is this setup possible at all within snowflake? That is, can we say that in this situation, the schema has two owners, or only one owner?

I have setup the inheritance for Role A to Role B, and it says that the both the roles have ownership privilege, and Role B got its ownership via inheritance from Role A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to set up Role B to inherit from Role A except in the one specific circumstance of ownership of a specific schema.

You need to re-think your role design in order to achieve the end result you want